# EnvJS/Rhino, setTimeout() not working

Tags: php, javascript, rhino, envjs

I currently set up EnvJS on my system (installed from [here](https://github.com/thatcher/env-js)).
My end goal is to load a page let it's javascript process for a few seconds, and then read the dom to get the information of interest. However I can not get setTimeout() to work to save my life (Or JQuery for that matter).

I have a php script that starts the process:

```
...
$ENVJS_PATH = "/var/www/project/src/envjs";
$RHINO_JAR = "rhino/js.jar";
$INIT_SCRIPT = "init.js";
$output = shell_exec("java -jar $ENVJS_PATH/$RHINO_JAR -opt -1 $ENVJS_PATH/$INIT_SCRIPT");
echo "Response from javascript:<br/> $output";
...
```

the init.js file looks like:

```
load('/var/www/project/src/envjs/dist/env.rhino.js');
print("Loaded env.rhino.js<br/>");

// temporarily commented out
//var url = "http://www.ken-soft.com";
//window.location = url;
//print("<br/>Loaded "+url+"<br/>");

// Problem starts here
var runAfterPause=function() {
  print("got here..."); // never gets called
  print(document.getElementById('some_id').innerHTML);
}
setTimeout(runAfterPause, 3000); //wait three seconds before continuing
// i have also tried setTimeout("runAfterPause()", 3000);
print("<br/>End<br/>");
```

Any knowledge on this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: not yet. I need to try out your answer. but I am spending a few days on another task, then I will get back to it. Sorry for not promptly trying your recommendations. I will try them as soon as I have free time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [env.rhino.1.2.js](http://www.envjs.com/dist/env.rhino.1.2.js) - and if the server OS hosting `rhino` is Ubuntu, then try `sudo apt-get install rhino` -- and call `rhino -opt -1 ...` instead of `java -jar ...`

Seems to run like this for me on Ubuntu 11.04, when ran directly on the shell - not sure if PHP's `shell_exec` may influence things or not..

EDIT: Indeed it is not really working; I looked through the source a bit, and could see that `setTimeout` relies on `Timer.prototype.start = function(){};`, which is apparently empty. Browsing further, the only thing that seems to deal with timing is `Envjs.wait()` - and using that, I can finally get a sort of a timed loop; however, note that it seems to be strictly single-threaded (synchronous) now:

```
print("loading " + 1.2);
load('env.rhino.1.2.js'); // takes a while ...
print("loaded " + 1.2);
console.log(window);

var c=0;
function timedCount() // like this, when setTimeout calls a string!
{
  c=c+1;
  print("c=" + c);

  if (c<10) // make a limit for the run of script:
  {
    var t;
    //~ t=window.setTimeout(timedCount(),100); // TypeError: fn is not a function, it is undefined.
    t=window.setTimeout("timedCount()",1000); // must have `t=...` - else it locks on return even w/ wait(0)!
    Envjs.wait(); // waits, but "timer error  undefined   TypeError: fn is not a function, it is undefined." if setTimout doesn't call string; wait(0) exits immediately
  } else Envjs.wait(0); // "reset": execute all timers and return; else here will be left hanging from previous wait()
}



// main:

timedCount();
//~ eval("timedCount()", null); // works the same

print("after timedCount()");
```

... and the results are:

```
$ sudo apt-get install rhino
$ wget https://github.com/thatcher/env-js

$ rhino -opt -1 test.js
loading 1.2
[  Envjs/1.6 (Rhino; U; Linux i386 2.6.38-11-generic; en-US; rv:1.7.0.rc2) Resig/20070309 PilotFish/1.2.13  ]
loaded 1.2
[Window]
a
c=1
c=2
c=3
c=4
c=5
c=6
c=7
c=8
c=9
c=10
after timedCount()
```

If I recall correctly, in a browser `setInterval` is asynchronous/multithreaded - indeed, in a browser [JavaScript Shell 1.4](http://www.squarefree.com/shell/shell.html), the almost same code:

```
var c=0;
function timedCount() 
{
  c=c+1;
  print("c=" + c);

  if (c<10)  {
    var t;
    t=window.setTimeout("timedCount()",1000); 
  }
}

timedCount();
print("after timedCount()");
```

produces:

```
c=1
after timedCount()
c=2
c=3
c=4
c=5
c=6
c=7
c=8
c=9
c=10
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback method is defined after the assignation. Try putting it before setTimeout

Comment: Sorry about that. I copied and pasted incorrectly :P My actual code has it in the right order.(I just edited the post)

Comment: Another thing worth commenting on is that `setTimeout( "print('x');", 1000 );` doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 0):

print is a method of window.

It's used to print a page, with a printer...

There might be a conflict with it and your print method.

Comment: print() works fine in all other contexts on the script. So i'm not too sure if it's the print function. but i'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 things i want you to try for debugging. At least visually i cannot see something wrong in yout code, unless someone see it.

first does your function work when you call it by itself? not inside the set Timeout

```
var runAfterPause=function() {
  print("got here..."); 
  print(document.getElementById('some_id').innerHTML);
}

// call function by it self
runAfterPause();
```

2nd try running it as an anonymous function inside your setTimeout;

```
var delay = setTimeout(function () {
   print("got here..."); // never gets called
   print(document.getElementById('some_id').innerHTML);
},3000);
```

this should help you debug your code and see where the error is.