# How do you run JavaScript script through the Terminal?

Tags: javascript, terminal

For instance, if you were to run a Python script you would type *python filename.py* or if you wanted to run a C program *make filename* then *./ filename*. How do you do this with *.js* files?

Comment: @BLUC It's called an executable.

Comment: executable, application, program, or binary.  And on a more helpful note, you'll need a JavaScript interpreter, like V8 or Rhino, or one of the other 1000 ones I'm forgetting.

Comment: @OliverWeiler it's not as easily applicable in general situations as some other languages, but I do believe it can have it's applications outside of web pages :).

Comment: An application of JavaScript is in Unity 3D

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You would need a JavaScript engine (such as [Mozilla's Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)) in order to evaluate the script - exactly as you do for Python, though the latter ships with the standard distribution.

If you have Rhino (or alternative) installed and on your path, then running JS can indeed be as simple as

```
> rhino filename.js
```

It's worth noting though that while JavaScript is simply a language in its own right, a lot of particular scripts assume that they'll be executing in a browser-like environment - and so try to access global variables such as `location.href`, and create output by appending DOM objects rather than calling `print`.

If you've got hold of a script which was written for a web page, you may need to wrap or modify it somewhat to allow it to accept arguments from stdin and write to stdout.  (I believe Rhino has a mode to emulate standard browser global vars which helps a lot, though I can't find the docs for this now.)

Comment: FYI, difference between rhino and spidermonkey (both are Mozilla creations): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563909/rhino-vs-spidermonkey

Comment: On Debian / Ubuntu: 'apt-get install rhino' and binary is called js.

Comment: I don't know if you feel the same thing, but I'm finding rhyno pretty fragile and buggy... (running Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: This work for me, use print("msg") for debugging than using console.log()

Answer (score 466):

Another answer would be the NodeJS!

> Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run across distributed devices.

Using terminal you will be able to start it using `node` command.

```
$ node
> 2 + 4
6
>
```

***Note***: If you want to exit just type

```
.exit
```

You can also run a JavaScript file like this:

```
node file.js
```

[**« Install it NOW »**](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: @NadirSampaoli Yes, it's a new technology that it's really great!

Comment: The only downside (if you want to call it that) is that node is always on "strict mode". Is it correct?

Comment: @NadirSampaoli Hmmm, I am not sure. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9031888/1420197

Comment: @NadirSampaoli I doubt that it counts as a "downside". Strict mode is better for everyone.

Comment: Any advice on wrapping a javascript into final ‘consumer ’command, the user doesn't have to care about? As in `$> sudo apt-get install myFancyCmd` followed by `$>myFancyCmd hello.jpg -w 1234`?

Comment: Just a note that you can install Node via Homebrew by issuing this terminal command: `brew install node`

Comment: On Ubuntu 14, `node` is [Ham Radio](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/AX25-HOWTO/), not JavaScript.  So try the Ubuntu answer to this question.

Comment: @Yatrix I am not wrong, Chrome and node use the same JS engine. Checked the `new Date()` and, indeed, the node REPL displays it in a different way, but `(new Date()).toString()` is the same in both. It won't affect the functionality of the script.

Comment: @Yatrix That's what I mentioned above: when stringifying the dates, you will get exactly the same results. The way how they are displayed in the REPLs may be different (but the value is the same).

Answer (score 137):

If you have **MacOS** you can get `jsc` a javascript console by typing on Terminal.app:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/Current/Helpers/jsc
```

On older versions of OS X, the **jsc** command is located at:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/jsc
```

You could also run one of your .js script by adding its name as an argument for jsc, like this:

```
jsc your_awesome_script_name.js
```

**Notice**: I use `console.log()` during development but jsc needs the `debug()` function instead.

On **Ubuntu** you have some nice [ECMAScript shells](http://discerning.com/burstproject.org/build/doc/shells.html) at your disposal. Between them it's worth to mention **[SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey)**. You can add It by `sudo apt-get install spidermonkey`

On **Windows** as other people said you can rely on `cscript` and `wscript` directly built on the OS.

I would add also another :) *way of thinking to the problem*, if you have time and like to learn new things i'd like to mention [coffee-script](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) that has its own compiler/console and gives you super-correct Javascript out. You can try it also on your browser (link "try coffeescript").

**UPDATE July 2021:**
You can also install and use the brilliant [QuickJS](https://bellard.org/quickjs/) which on OS X could be installed via `brew install quickjs`. Then an interactive console will be available at your propmt with `qjs`

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't support SpiderMonkey since 10.04. (Do you know why? http://askubuntu.com/q/180572/482285 )

Comment: @maciek SpiderMonkey is still available for Ubuntu but under another name: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libmozjs-24-bin

Comment: @maciek ...so you can do:
`sudo apt-get install libmozjs-24-bin`
and the use `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/js24 /usr/bin/js` to use it with *js* in your shell.

Comment: By the way `console.log` works fine with *node*, installed on Ubuntu with `sudo apt install nodejs`. Perfect for a `console.log('hey world, here I am')` kinda app, which you can run with `node hey.js`.

Comment: On newer versions of the now called _MacOS_ the path to jsc is `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/Current/Helpers/jsc`.

Answer (score 34):

Use node.js for that, here is example how to install `node` by using `brew` on mac:

```
brew update && install node
```

Then run your program by typing `node filename.js`, and you can use `console.log()` for output.

Comment: This goes great in combination with https://github.com/remy/nodemon wich will watch any javascript file and rerun it on any change. So just run it with nodemon yourjavascript.js

Comment: Don't you mean `brew install node`? `install node` on its own won't really do anything.

Answer (score 14):

It is crude, but you can open up the Javascript console in Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+J) and paste the text contents of the *.js file and hit Enter.

Comment: Actually is not that crude, and I was amazed that nobody talked about `console`.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this process?

Answer (score 13):

**If you're using MacBook.**

1. Set up `node.js` in your system and open up the terminal
2. Navigate to the directory, where the js file is saved.
3. To execute run `node <filename.js>`

example, if filename is `script.js` run `node script.js`

Comment: node is close to javascript but it is not exactly javascript, eg, javascript doesn't support file IO, there is require function by default either; it might not be a good way to test javascript file

Answer (score 6):

You need installed JS engine like `Node`, then use a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line in very first line of your file, like this:

script.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log('Hello terminal');
```

after that you must set executable permission:

`chmod +x script.js`

And run it

```
./script.js
```

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: chmod u+x is better than +x because just add executable permits to the user and not to others.  All this example is if you have Linux or Mac, not for Windows, worth to say.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, if you're just looking to play around with Javascript a nice in browser option is [Codecademy's](http://labs.codecademy.com/) Javascript Lab.

They also have a Python and Ruby IDE.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on a Windows PC, you can use WScript.exe or CScript.exe

Just keep in mind that you are not in a browser environment, so stuff like `document.write` or anything that relies on the `window` object will not work, like `window.alert`. Instead, you can call `WScript.Echo` to output stuff to the prompt.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Is there one for Ubuntu, Google Chrome?

Comment: You should have put that piece of vital information in the question. Sorry, I'm a Windows geek - I don't know much about Ubuntu. Besides, you will probably not have access to Google Chrome when running javascript from an Ubuntu shell prompt. EDIT: Andrzej Doyle's answer is the way to go for you.

Answer (score 4):

I tried researching that too but instead ended up using [jsconsole.com](http://jsconsole.com/) by Remy Sharp (he also created jsbin.com). I'm running on Ubuntu 12.10 so I had to [create a special icon](https://github.com/RafalChmiel/blog/blob/master/February%202013/08-02-13%20-%20Make%20jsconsole.com%20Seem%20Like%20a%20Native%20App.md#make-jsconsolecom-seem-like-a-native-app) but if you're on Windows and use Chrome simply go to Tools>Create Application Shortcuts (note this doesn't work very well, or at all in my case, on Ubuntu). This site works very like the Mac `jsc` console: actually it has some cool features too (like loading libraries/code from a URL) that I guess `jsc` does not.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu, install [image: a link to install] [libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-bin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-bin) and use `/usr/bin/jsc` ([manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/jsc.1.html)).

Comment: Simpler for Ubuntu 14: `sudo apt-get install nodejs`; `/usr/bin/nodejs foo.js`.  Note that it's v0.10.25, a little old.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do to run a js file via bash is type:
`$ node filename.js`

This is similar to in python, when you do:
`$ python filename.py`

Answer (score 2):

This is a "roundabout" solution but you could use [ipython](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#alternative-for-experienced-python-users-installing-jupyter-with-pip)

Start ipython notebook from terminal:

`$ ipython notebook`

It will open in a browser where you can run the javascript

[image]

Answer (score 2):

All the answers above are great, I see one thing missing and could be considered for running `javascripts(*.js)` files, the *unrelated* brother of `javascript` the `Java`.

`JDK` comes up with two nice tools, could be utilized for executing `javascripts`.
Here are command goes like. Make sure to navigate to `JDK\bin`.

```
 jjs example.js
```

Its comes up with another `commmand` tool that goes like this-

```
 jrunscript example.js
```

I hope this may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `phantomjs` Download phantomjs depending on the system (my case is Max OSX) from [phantomjs.org](http://phantomjs.org/)
.You should put the path to phantomjs installation folder on the top of your javascript file. eg. `#!./bin/phantomjs` Save your code. Go to the terminal where your javascript is saved and you can run using *`> phantomjs filename.js`*

Answer (score -1):

Technically, [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) isn't proper JavaScript as we know it, since there isn't a [Document Object Model (DOM)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction). For instance, JavaScript scripts that run in the browser will not work. At all. The solution would be to run JavaScript with a headless browser. Fortunately there is a project still active: Mozilla Firefox has a [headless mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode

```
$ /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -headless index.html
*** You are running in headless mode.
```