# Any way to force strict mode in node?

Tags: node.js

Could not find this answer anywhere, but I did find several mailing lists where this was discussed, these are rather old however and I have no idea if this is implemented or not.

Is there anyway to force using strict mode in node.js?

Writing `"use strict";` in all my .js files... well, i prefer it being forced to using strict mode, rather than adding extra boilerplate.

Comment: I would highly suggest checking out [this much updated answer (rather than the dangerous answer which was chosen)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51970329/124486)

Answer (score 224, accepted):

According to Lloyd you can now place

```
"use strict";
```

at the top of your file in **node >= 0.10.7**, but if you want your whole app to run in strict (**including external modules**) you can do this

> node --use_strict

Comment: eek: fs.js:1497
      function emit() {
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at top level or immediately within another function.

Comment: one of the modules you're using is not following the strict rules

Comment: oh O_o, so you cant use the filesystem if you force strict? which version of node are you using, im not getting this on v0.8.12

Comment: 'v0.8.16' <--- hmm odd. Let me go verify.

Comment: 01734a-j03m:node-limiter j03m$ node --use_strict test/exampleLimiter.js

fs.js:1497
      function emit() {
      ^^^^^^^^
[REDACTED]
var vows = require('vows'),
 assert = require('assert');
var Limiter = require('../limiter.js');

var namespace = 'vowstest';
var mockUid = '1234556';

var Membase = require('memcached');
var m = new Membase("127.0.0.1:11211");

Comment: that's of course using vows, assert and memcached, but it's definitely thrown in fs.

Comment: In node v0.9.x and newer the `--use_strict` flag works as expected.

Comment: in node v0.8 with `--use_strict` I got `ReferenceError: global is not defined` in `node.js` itself

Comment: Note that `--use_strict` will set strict mode to the whole application, include all exteneral modules, which are out of your controls.

Answer (score 60):

In node 0.10.7 you can enforce strict mode at file level by placing `"use strict";` at the top of your file. Finally!

Answer (score 33):

Just use `"use strict";` at the top of applicable files. I know it's tempting to try to cut out boilerplate, but it simply can not be done in Javascript. The node flag which shall not be named<sup>[1]</sup>

- is undocumented, and unsupported by Node itself.
- has faced [proposals to remove it.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6429)
- is node-specific and is not supported in any other JavaScript engine.
- is unstandardized.
- it is **not** the same as `"use strict";` because it is a compiler global, and like all globals you're potentially adversely impacting someone else's code.
- everything is subject to bugs. strict mode and sloppy-mode may be subject to different bugs. that is to say, some [strict mode bugs are unique to strict mode](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1041128)

Some other programmers may think this is similar to `-wALL` or the like, it's not. This is standardized functionality that you're enabling in an ad-hoc fashion (breaking the standard) and changing everyone's compiler semantics.

### Footnotes

1. The node flag is `--use_strict`. **Don't use it**.

Comment: Can you tell me where you found that it is "unsupported by Node?" Is that just inferred from the fact that it's not documented?

Comment: Mostly. And because it's not a Node thing at all, it's a pass through to v8.

Comment: Thank you! I wondered why I couldn't find it in the [Node cli docs](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html).

Comment: proposals to remove it was rejected/closed https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6429

Answer (score 27):

You can also use

https://npmjs.org/package/use-strict

that is, write once

```
require('use-strict')
```

or even take a step forward and use

https://npmjs.org/package/node-strict

Please note that `use-strict` will turn on strict more on every module required after invocation.

If you prefer a not invasive approach, I wrote another module

https://www.npmjs.org/package/strict-mode

which enables strict mode only in your package. I think that is more a "Do What I Mean" solution.

Answer (score 20):

You can also provide the strict flag on the shebang interpreter directive.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --use_strict
```

But currently (at least pre v0.9.x) it suffers the same problems described by the comments in @chad-scira's answer discuss.

Comment: `env` doesn't allow you to pass parameters like that, does it?

Comment: Works for me, on OSX 10.9.4.

Comment: yeah - still exemplifies a terrible enforced convention, that being two competing lines of code that have to be at the top of a file.

Comment: Beware, `env` will work with extra parameters like that on OSX, but not on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using CommonJS (NodeJS uses CommonJS modularization by default) there's no strict mode unless you include `"use strict"` in the file or execute node with the `--use_strict` flag

But in ECMAScript modules, strict mode is by default. You can enable it adding  `"type": "module"` to package.json

Comment: Do you have a source?

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that ESLint enforces strict mode by default. It won't stop you from running `node` on a file that doesn't adhere to strict mode of course, but if you have ESLint as a required part of your build and CI process, then developers will only be able to commit strict-mode code.