# Are there js environments which support strict mode only?

Tags: javascript, strict-mode

I am developing a lib currently, which is relying on `arguments.callee.caller`. This is not compatible with `"use strict"`, so it throws an error when the caller function was defined in strict mode. I catch those errors, they does not really matter, since the important part is not defined in strict mode. Is there an environment which supports only strict mode, and so is not compatible with this lib?

Comment: Node can be forced to execute all code in strict mode with a command-line flag if that is what you want to know.

Comment: What do you need `.caller` for?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! I wanted to know something like that. :-) I use the caller to do something like `Error.captureStackTrace(o, fn)` does in a non-v8 environment: https://github.com/inf3rno/e3/blob/master/lib/stackAdapter/StackAdapter/non-v8/FrameStringSource.js#L16 I test currently for `arguments.callee.caller` to do graceful degradation, but that test does not catch the error by strict mode. I need to modify that.

Comment: @Bergi Is there any non-node environment which enforces strict mode? Or is there at least one browser which does not support arguments.callee.caller, but supports ES5? The current code uses `Error.prepareStackTrace()` by node and chrome, so they are not affected.

Comment: I don't know any (which doesn't mean there are none), but i'm not sure why you'd want to know. Either there is one, and you don't support it, or there is none and everything is ok. Just wrap the access attempt in a `try`/`catch` and be done with it.

Comment: Btw, you might want to have a look at all the stack-trace-retrieving libraries out there and see how they do it.

Comment: @Bergi I want to decide whether I want to support those environments. That's the point of this SO question...

Comment: @Bergi Afaik only https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js is worth to mention, but it does browser detection and has it's own api. I don't like their approach.

Comment: @Bergi Add an answer with the command line code that forces strict mode, so I can accept it.

Comment: I guess if there actually are any such environments, then you *cannot* support them anyway - at least not without finding another trick. But regardless, I recommend YAGNI - if nobody knows such an environment, it's not relevant. But if you really want to know, check the lists of supported environments of other stack-tracing libs.

Comment: @Bergi Actually I can more or less support it, but it is much harder than with `arguments.callee.caller`. I'll check, but I don't think they would help. At least I don't want to install a lot of browsers just to try this out.

Comment: I would be surprised if `arguments.callee` was not caught by one of the various lint tools.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks! I'll remove code that uses `arguments.callee` if I can. I just realized it is not allowed by strict mode either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an environment which supports only strict mode?

You can configure Node.js to do that, see [Any way to force strict mode in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9031888/1048572):

```
node --use_strict
```

Answer (score 0):

Any modern JS environment will always have strict mode in the context of [certain ES6 contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283935/which-ecmascript-6-features-imply-strict-mode). Namely:

> - Module code is always strict mode code.
> - All parts of a *ClassDeclaration* or a *ClassExpression* are strict mode code.

Of course, the real answer here is **don't use `arguments.callee.caller`** if you want to be future proof.

But if you want to avoid the strict mode limitation, you can access [Function.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) directly with named functions. This is highly discouraged, since it's a non-standard feature.