# Receiving strict mode warning while running node 4.4.7

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, let, strict

I believe node v4.4.7 supports ES6. However node refuses to compile my program:

```
user1-$ node -v
v4.4.7

user1-$ node index.js
event-service.js:85
      let sql = 'SELECT * FROM group_events where id = ?';
      ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
```

I want to avoid 'use strict'. Any other options?

Comment: Maybe this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031888/any-way-to-force-strict-mode-in-node

Comment: I don't want to place 'use strict' on top of every file. Are there any other options ?

Comment: I believed node was running in strict mode by default in v4.x. Wierd. Try to run `node --use_strict index.js`

Comment: Why not switch to a newer node version? The current stable version has much better ES6 support.

Comment: @generalhenry  under node downloads.. the version that pops up is v4.5.. I am not that far off

Comment: node.js v6 is the latest node.js version with the most ES6 support.  And, regardless you should be happy to run your code in strict mode as it will save you many accidental headaches.

Comment: The latest node version is 6.6, it is not the long term support version, but it will become LTS on October 1st

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT place your response as an answer so I can mark it so

Comment: @generalhenry will I not have to use --use_strict option in node 6.6 ?

Comment: Yes and no.  In 6.6 you no longer need strict mode for let, but strict mode still applies it's usual set of changes to the runtime.  If/when node switches to es2015 modules you would no longer need to use strict at all since they are always run in strict mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run `node --use_strict index.js` to force it using strict mode