# Accessing functions (prototype extension) inside another function - Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the javascript I'm trying to run in the terminal via [jsc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532960/how-do-you-run-javascript-script-through-the-terminal#answer-8533028):

calc_real_weights.js:

```
getElementWithLowestCount(someMatrix)

Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(null, this);
};

function getElementWithLowestCount(countAndWeightMatrix){
    aux = []
    for(var i = 0; i < countAndWeightMatrix.length; i++){
        if (countAndWeightMatrix[i][0] < aux.min()){
          var min = countAndWeightMatrix[i];
        }
        aux.push(countAndWeightMatrix[i][0]);
    }
    return min;
}
```

The error:

```
Borjas-MacBook-Pro:Algorithm borjagvo$ jsc calc_real_weights.js
Exception: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'aux.min()')
getElementWithLowestCount@calc_real_weights.js:37:46
calcRealWights@calc_real_weights.js:46:45
global code@calc_real_weights.js:18:33
```

It looks like `getElementWithLowestCount` doesn't see the Array prototype extension. How can I make it to see it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problems comes from the fact that you are calling `getElementWithLowestCount` before changing the `Array` prototype. Try moving your call to `getElementWithLowestCount` after the two `Array.prototipe` blocks.