# Issues running haxe application in osx terminal with createjs library

Tags: command-line, haxe, createjs, haxelib

When running this command

```
haxe -main Main.hx
```

I'm getting this error

```
Main.hx:2: characters 7-33 : Type not found : createjs.easeljs.Container
```

Main.hx

```
package ;
import createjs.easeljs.Container;
import createjs.easeljs.Shape;
import createjs.easeljs.Stage;
import createjs.easeljs.Text;
import createjs.easeljs.Ticker;
import js.Browser;
import js.html.CanvasElement;
import js.html.Element;
```

I've included the javascript file for the createjs library and I also installed the library using the command

```
haxe install createjs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the createjs haxelib with the `-lib` argument during compilation:

`haxe -main Main.hx -lib createjs`

Comment: I'm getting this error now but its pointing to code in the createjs library

`/Users/Vincent/Repos/skytroops/bin/js/createjs/1,5,8/createjs/easeljs/ColorMatrix.hx:13: characters 8-50 : Invalid number of type parameters for Array`

Comment: That's a different isuse, and one I can't reproduce. What does your code look like, and what's your Haxe version (`haxe -version`)?

Comment: My haxe version is 3.2.1

Comment: Managed to reproduce it - this is an issue with the extern definition. Changing `Array` to `Array<Dynamic>` in line 13 and 14 in that file fixes the compiler error. I suggest you open an issue on the [CreateJS-Haxe GitHub repo](https://github.com/nickalie/CreateJS-Haxe).

Comment: Awesome! Also this is a different question, but how do I run the .js file in terminal?

Comment: While that [might be possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8533057/2631715), it's quite unusual. .js files are [generally executed in a browser](http://haxe.org/manual/target-javascript-getting-started.html#run-the-javascript).

Comment: ...unless explicitly targeted at non-browser environments (such as Node.js), which is not the case here, given that it works with HTML5 canvas.