# How to run php file with js code in it on commandline?

Tags: javascript, php, command-line, execute

I have to execute one php file via commandline in my linux docker and I am able to execute it but the issue is that js code written in the same file is not getting executed and I am not able to achieve the desired functionality. So please direct with me in correct direction.

Comment: JavaScript runs in the user's browser. If there's no browser it doesn't run. Can you rewrite the JS functionality in PHP?

Comment: Javascript need to be interpreted. PHP cannot do this. It only interprets PHP sources.

Comment: php can certainly start the js interpretter though'

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [`passthru`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) and execute the js with [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) in PHP to start the JS interpretter...

I just ran this test from the Mac command line

```
# Made a directory to test in
$ mkdir jsphptest && cd jsphptest

# made a test php file
$ touch test.php

# put some PHP code in the PHP file that tells it to run a javascript file
$ echo '<?php passthru("node test.js"); ?>' > test.php

# create the above references js file
$ touch test.js

# Put some JS code in the new JS file that logs some stuff into the console
$ echo 'console.log("this is javascript");' > test.js

# run the php file
$ php test.php

#outputs: this is javascript
```

Answer (score -1):

javascript is client based language so you can not execute it this way.
Javascript is being executed by browser

If you persist to execute it . Look at this link
[How do you run JavaScript script through the Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532960/how-do-you-run-javascript-script-through-the-terminal)

Comment: Not browsers, by javascript engines, usually used in web browsers.

Comment: I said it generally